# PHP and JSON (API)

Tags: php, json, exact-online, picqer-exact-php-client

**What is going wrong**
I'm trying to make an api between exactonline and autotask. I'm already linked to the database between these, but now I do not come any further to transfer the data between these two.

**Script**

script1(exactOnline)

```
try {
    $result = array();
    $journals = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\Journal($connection);
    $result   = $journals->get();
    foreach ($result as $journal) {
       $result[]= $journal->Description;
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    json_encode(array(get_class($e) . ' : ' . $e->getMessage()));
}
```

script2(exactOnline)

```
namespace Picqer\Financials\Exact;

/**
 * Class Journal
 *
 * @package Picqer\Financials\Exact
 * @see https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=financialJournals
 *
 * @property String $Code BIC code of the bank where the bank account is held
 * @property Int32 $Division Division code
 * @property String $Description Description of BankAccount
 * @property Guid $ID Primary Key
 * @property String $Type Bank account number. Is mandatory for Journals that have Type = Bank
 */
class Journal extends Model
{
    use Query\Findable;
    use Persistance\Storable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Code',
        'Division',
        'Description',
        'ID',
        'Type',
    ];

    protected $url = 'financial/Journals';
}
```

**Output**

```
[{"Code":"10","Description":"Kasboek","Division":1741496,"ID":"846af4e2-209d-44aa-84f2-068ae65b69b5","Type":10},{"Code":"90","Description":"Memoriaal","Division":1741496,"ID":"91fc95a4-765e-4d8b-8271-63884be5e480","Type":90},{"Code":"95","Description":"Activamutaties","Division":1741496,"ID":"8ec1491e-51a4-46b8-87f0-a3134c83af4c","Type":90},{"Code":"60","Description":"Inkoopboek","Division":1741496,"ID":"11b1d819-4cdc-4f8c-9d60-aac2359c230b","Type":22},{"Code":"20","Description":"Bank","Division":1741496,"ID":"f8afe3cc-bcf1-4932-9fe0-b761ad48618f","Type":12},{"Code":"70","Description":"Verkoopboek","Division":1741496,"ID":"b4afe081-7f6b-46c7-9742-ea22302a4d55","Type":20},"Kasboek","Memoriaal","Activamutaties","Inkoopboek","Bank","Verkoopboek"]
```

**Question**
My question is how can I get for example Kasboek as an input in my Autotask script input like this so i can post it >

```
$ticket->AccountID = 'Kasboek';
$ticket->DueDateTime = '2015-12-17';
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you have an example of where you are wanting this information decoded, or how you consider it to be "easier to specific data" (whatever that means)?

Comment: @randall thank you for saying i updated my post I hope you under stand it now.

Comment: You want your second script to read the first script output json via http and convert it to Journal class objects?

Comment: You want script 2 output in script 1? and what is autotask btw?